# What is the difference between a top and side post battery?

Tags: battery, battery-testing

I'm looking in to getting a battery analyzer and whilst looking through the manuals, I came across an entry where you have to tell it whether the battery is side or top posts.

What difference does this make to the test the analyzer performs whether the terminals are on the top or the side?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've not seen anything stating one way or the other. Never heard anything which would make them different or why they'd need to be accounted for differently. I mean, if both batteries are wet cell style, there really shouldn't make a difference. I don't have a clue why there'd be any difference.

Comment: Perhaps because the battery's installation in the car may restrict the angle or direction from which the analyzer connector(s) meet the terminals - side posts or top posts may have different clearances in different directions.

Comment: Seemed strange to me too.  As far as I see it, a terminal is a terminal regardless of whether it is mounted on the top or the side...